# MacBook Pro HDD partitionning lasts longer then expected

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, partitioning

I had 2 partition in my Mac : Macintosh HD and Back-up. I wanted to erase the Back-up partition to increase Macintosh HD's capacity. I had no problems to erase the Back-up partition but resizing the Macintosh HD is lasting much more then I expected... It has been around 30 minutes and says : `Preparing to partition disk`. I did partitioning and resizing lots of times before but lasted only a few minutes. What should I do?

Comment: If the hard drive light is active, wait !!  (I'm not a mac person, but I'm positing that there is a lot of information which needs to be moved arround, and copying is a very slow process)

Comment: There is no hard drive light on Macs!

Comment: Leave it this way for a couple of hours. If it's still at "preparing", you could abort it, give your Mac a restart and try again. Also, make sure you stopped the Time Machine so it's not trying to backup any changes to that partition you want to delete.

Comment: Actually the delete part is done, no problems there, Time Machine is off. It's just the resizing process of the main partition.

Comment: Patience, then! :)

Comment: Tried to repair disk, resizing from Backup HD but still the same think...